# CSS through JavaScript: changing class "interrupted" by style change

Tags: javascript, html, css

Changing class for DIV through JavaScript works great until I "interrupt it" by changing style attribute for that DIV.

case 0: changes left to 400

case 1: changes left to 600

case 2: doesn't work!

Why's that?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
    <style type="text/css">
        .pos1 {left: 200px; top:400px;}
        .pos2 {left: 400px; top:400px;}
        .pos3 {left: 800px; top:400px;}
    </style>
</head>

<body>
        <div id = "img" class = "pos1" style="position:absolute;"> <img src="gfx/1n.png"> </div>


        <script type="text/javascript">
            var action = 0;
            window.onmousedown = function(event){makeAction();}

            function makeAction() {
                switch(action) {
                    case 0: action++; document.getElementById('img').className = "pos2"; break
                    case 1: action++; document.getElementById('img').style.left = "600px"; break;
                    case 2: action++; document.getElementById('img').className = "pos3"; break;
                }

            }

        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Shouldn't there be a semi-colon after the first break?

Comment: @MyHeadHurts Semi-colons in JavaScript are [optional](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-7.9): "When a break token is encountered and a LineTerminator is encountered before the next token, a semicolon is automatically inserted after the break token."

Comment: @michielvoo Thanks - I didn't know that. I didn't think it was the problem since the issue was with the third `case`, but I thought it was worth mentioning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the style attribute you set in the second case overrides the style from the class you assign in the last case.

After this first case the image tag is

```
<img class="pos2" ... />
```

So it's positioned left by 400px.

After the second case the image tag is

```
<img class="pos2" style="left: 600px" ... />
```

Even though it still has class pos2, **the style attribute overrides** the left positioning, so it's now positioned left by 600px.

After the last case the image tag is:

```
<img class="pos3" style="left: 600px;" .. />
```

Even though it now has class pos3, **the style attribute *still* overrides** the left positioning, so it remains positioned left by 600px.

Understand that CSS does not depend on *when* it's applied, but that it always follows the *rules of specificity*. And the rules state that style rules in the style attribute of a tag override style rules from a class.

You can override the rule using the `important` keyword:

```
.pos3 {left: 800px !important; top:400px;}
```

Comment: This explains everything. So in order to make my code working I need to clear the style.left value (`document.getElementById('img').style.left = ""`) to make `case 3` happen. Thanks a lot for a prompt explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Since you set the left property via `<object>.style.left` you assigned it as if it were an inline rule and this can be overriden only with another inline rule (or a change in rule specificity , e.g. using `!important` in your class).